# removing salt and pepper noise using wiener filter in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing

How do I restore an RGB image which has salt&pepper filter applied using Wiener filter in Matlab? Here is my code

```
image=imread('1.jpg');
sandpimage = imnoise(image, 'salt & pepper', 0.05);
```

I guess I have to use deconvwnr function but it requires a second parameter PSF to be given

Comment: .jpg images are 3D truecolor images in Matlab, if you can convert such pictures in .tif or .png (which both support 2D pictures) you can easily use `wiener2()` or the Median Filter (`midfilt2()`) which also has good performances in terms of s&p image restoration.

Comment: I've converted the image to both .png and .tiff and it doesn't help. Still getting 
 'Error using wiener2>ParseInputs (line 139)
WIENER2 does not support 3D truecolor images as an input.'
And I can't use median, I need exactly Wiener filter for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply the filter separately to each color layer (R, G, B):

```
sandpimage_filtered = sandpimage;

for layer=1:3
    sandpimage_filtered(:,:,layer) = wiener2(sandpimage(:,:,layer), [5 5]);
end

%//plot the images to see the difference
subplot(2,1,1)
imshow(sandpimage)
subplot(2,1,2)
imshow(sandpimage_filtered)
```

In the above code I am using a window size of `5x5`. You can change the window size inside the `wiener2` function

Comment: Works great! One more thing, how do I find filtering fault? Cheers!

Comment: @Sheldon filtering fault? Im not familiar with that term :P

Comment: I mean, how do I compare two images to get difference between them in percent to make a conclusion on how effective the filter was? Sorry, for a bit of complication :)

Comment: @Sheldon Usually for images, a good metric is the signal-to-noise ratio (SNR). Take a look here: http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/snr.html